# Connecting to Db2 on z/OS via JDBC using IBM JDK vs OpenJDK

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-zos, ibm-jdk

I am able to connect to Db2 on z/OS with the IBM universal JDBC driver file db2jcc4.jar using IBM JDK 1.8 that is bundled with WebSphere 9. Every thing works fine and I can browse the catalog and execute queries. I used Squirrel SQL version 4.0.0.

But when I switch my JDK to the Open JDK 8 or 12 while keeping everything else the same, I get the following error. What should be done to fix this error? What is the difference between IBM JDK and Open JDK, which causes the DB2 connection to work with one JDK and fail with the other?

[image: error when using Open JDK 12]

Comment: Is the z/OS database using `DATA_ENCRYPT`? Is this a direct connection or via Db2 Connect?

Comment: This question is more about configuration than programming. Ensure the openjdk has the unlimited cryptographic key length enabled. Ensure the required security providers are enabled in the java.security.  Don't hide error codes/error messages in graphics, they are not searchable, instead copy paste as plain text in your question.

Comment: Probably server certificate is not present in the keystores that comes with non-IBM JDKs.

Comment: @kkuduk : I do not know that. Since I at least have a way to connect to the database using the IBM JDK and Squirrel SQL; Is there a way I can find out if it is DATA_ENCRYPT?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of matching articles of your case:
**JDBC application may receive error "Security mechanism not supported"** 
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/jdbc-application-may-receive-error-security-mechanism-not-supported

**Resolving The Problem**

Set the following property :

securityMechanism = ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD_AND_DATA_SECURITY (13)

Alternatively you can set property retryWithAlternativeSecurityMechanism to YES(1).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried both the properties. But neither of them solves my issue of connecting to the Db2 on z/OS using OpenJDK.

Comment: Sad news.  Now, the issue may be related to OpenJDK so it is recommended to use IBM JDK.

Answer (score 0):

According to IBM's documentation for their IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ, error code -4214 is an "Authorization failed" error -- and you know that much. But you can get more specific information about the problem if you call SQLException.getMessage. I think you may have done that already, but it's not entirely clear.

My semi-educated guess is that you haven't yet followed the configuration steps in IBM's driver documentation in the section "Configuring the Java Runtime Environment to Use SSL":

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_t0054066.html

You'll have to apply some common sense knowledge to those instructions to adapt them for the OpenJDK, and this might not be an IBM supported combination depending on what/how you do it. If you can somehow use the IBMJSSE2 Provider, that'd be nice.

I think Mao and Mustaccio probably have the right ideas, and probably you're just missing the server certificate in your truststore. The instructions linked above walk you through how to configure that.